# Rails model: before_save {self.password = password.strip} vs. before_save {password.strip!}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-save

I have a few lines in my User model to strip leading/tailing white-space from the User's email and password. The original code looked like this:

```
before_save {self.email = email.strip}
before_save {self.password = password.strip}
before_save {self.password_confirmation = password_confirmation.strip}
```

This passed my test:

```
test "password entry should ignore leading/tailing whitespace" do
 @user = User.create(name: "M", email: " foo@bar.com", 
  password: "  password", password_confirmation: "  password")
 assert @user.authenticate("password")
 assert_not @user.authenticate(" password")
end
```

Now I tried to re-factor it:

```
before_save {email.strip!}
before_save {password.strip!}
before_save {password_confirmation.strip!}
```

This works fine for my email test, but it's broken the password test above. So, the question is, how is the original version actually different from the re-factored code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `password.strip!` because in fact there's no such field as `password` - it is a setter `password=` that generates and stores password hash.

Comment: I think I get it. So while there is a reader method for @password, the code where the password gets hashed only occurs in the setter method. So it lets me call self.password.strip!, but it doesn't pass the result to the hash-function. It changes the instance variable, but the change doesn't make it to the database. The original version did work because it uses the setter-method instead. Does that sound right?